# What is real $R$ so that every subset of Euclidean space with diameter one is inside a ball of radius $R$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, spheres

What is infimum of real numbers $R$ so that for every $n$ every $S \subseteq \mathbb{E}^n$, for which $d(S) = \sup\{|x-x'| \mid x,x' \in S \} = 1$, is inside some closed $n$-ball of radius $R$? In particular, is this infimum $\sqrt{2}/2$ and is in fact every such $S$ inside closed ball of radius strictly less than $\sqrt{2}/2$?

Comment: Surely I can take the ball of diameter $1$ centered extremely far away from your $n$-sphere, and then it will not be contained in your $n$-sphere. So I think there is some constraint not specified in your question.

Comment: Do you have an example in mind showing that the answer can't be smaller than $\sqrt2$?

Comment: I edited the question, I had mistakenly used the diameter. That is, I guess $R = \sqrt{2}/2$ and not $R = \sqrt{2}$ . I believe $ \sqrt{2}/2$ is the limit of radius of circumscribed sphere of regular $n$-simplex.

Comment: @gnometorule That wasn't clear until this edit.

Comment: I seem to recall that [hypocycloids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocycloid) have interesting properties related to diameter, perhaps one might show up here.

Comment: Such sets will be bounded by n-simplexes, and those lie in their circumscribed sphere. I had stated what is I think a wrong formula for those spheres' radius, but this is what will be your $R$. It will not be *strictly* less, just less than or equal. For $n=3$ (triangle), yes, $R=\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: I edited the question to consider balls instead of spheres to be less confusing.

Comment: I'm at a total loss at this question: Why not $R=d(S)$? I would be happy if somebody could give me a counterexample.

Comment: @BernhardGeiger an equilateral triangle of side 1 requires $R\geq \sqrt 3 / 3$, which is greater than the $1/2$ required by a circle of diameter 1.

Comment: And I assume we're looking for the minimal such $R$.

Comment: @user73985: I see, thanks! $R=1$ would of course work, but this is too large... sorry, I was still confused by the first statement $R=\sqrt{2}$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jung's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jung%27s_theorem) gives the definitive answer to this question: Given any compact set $K\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ with ${\rm diam}(K)\leq1$ there is a unique ball $B_r\supset K$ of minimal radius, and $$r\leq\sqrt{{n\over 2(n+1)}}\ .$$